# Android: DatagramPacket got incorrect IP resource

Tags: android, udp

I've made an app that sends a message via udp and a Windows program in my laptop replies its information when receiving the meesage.
My Android app will record the message with its IP address. And I use **DatagramPacket.getAddress()** to get the address.

For some reasons, my app keeps sending messages and it also receives many redundant replies from the laptop.

The error is that *for some of **DatagramPacket** with the same message(from the same laptop), (DatagramPacket.)**getAddress()** returned 192.168.1.1(not the laptop address).*

I've done experiments and find the following:

> 1. Only found in Windows 10. (Not in Windows 7/8/8.1)
> 2. The wrong address must be 192.168.1.1
> 3. The heavy network traffic raises the possibility of this error

To avoid the bug, my Windows program sends its IP address and its information to my app now.
Because I don't know what went wrong!

Comment: You're broadcasting, so yo got a reply from another device, evidently the router. Why is this a surprise?

Comment: Sorry, I don't describe well. The message is from the laptop(192.168.1.82) but with address 192.168.1.1. That's why I am confused.